# Creating a dynamic add button swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, user-interface

How would I be able to create a button that works similarly to the add phone button in the contacts app? As shown below, to replicate it, I have a button on the right side that the type is *Add Contact* (appears as a plus in a circle) and on the right is a label. I then put them together in a stack view.

How does the contacts app have one large (bar) button that holds the image and the text? When tapping on the button (in the contacts app) it highlights the whole bar. This makes me believe that might have done this using a `UITableView`.

What's the best way to create a similar (bar) button as they did? Would this be easier to replicate if I used a `UITableView` instead?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a tableView.

They either constrained button's top to an empty tableView's bottom or they made this as an integral tableView and each time you **didSelectRowAt** it inserts a row at known position.

Suppose they either use a DataSource delegate method for rows insertion or a custom-made function wrapped in **tableView.beginUpdates()** and **tableView.endUpdates()** (reloads the table with animation)

Answer (score 0):

you should not use stackview to wrap both button and right text.because you also need tap event.and stack view not giving tapping event.

I think you should place your button and label inside UIView and than Assing UIControl as Class in Inspecter(not UIView).than Controll drag from Your View to Class File and select TouchUPinside event.**disabel user interaction of both button and Label otherwise event will not Fired.**

[image: Assign UIControll to UIView]

[image: Create TouchUpinsde event of UIControl]

and than Add above UIControll and other Component to either tableView or Vertical StackView.